# Ora*C PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "L" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: c, gcc, oracle10g, cygwin

Having this issue when running Pro*C in windows with cygwin

```
Syntax error at line 104, column 31, file C:\cygwin\usr\include\machine/_default_types.h:
Error at line 104, column 31 in file C:\cygwin\usr\include\machine/_default_types.h
#elif  defined(LLONG_MAX) && (LLONG_MAX > 0x7fffffff)
..............................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "L" when expecting one of the following:
```

config pcscfg.cfg file looks like this:

```
sys_include=
(C:\cygwin\usr\include,C:\Oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\precomp\public,C:\cygwin\usr\include\sys,C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.5.3\include)

ltype=short

define=(ORASTDARG)

code=kr_c 

parse=partial
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a pair of parenthesis.

Comment: where would I add the parenthesis ?

Comment: Before defined and at the EOL: `#elif  (defined(LLONG_MAX) && (LLONG_MAX > 0x7fffffff) )`You could also try to *remove* the parenthesis around `LLONG_MAX > 0x7fffffff`. Also: inspect the previous line. Could be a \r\n + backslash thing.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work...this file is _default_types.h from the gcc compiler library, so I doubt I have to do any changes to these library files...maybe something to do with Pro*C ?

Comment: My guess was indeed that there was something wrong with Pro*C. (Oracle+Microsoft+C := bad mix). BTW: you can look at the header files without affecting the libraries. You can even edit them, if you know what you are doing. Is this a fresh installation?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using

```
#ifdef ORA_PROC
    #include <apparently_evil_include_file.h>
#endif
```

to suppress the include that is including the evil thing,
as a possible workaround.

It effectively hides the include from the Pro*c preprocessor, while letting it be there for the compiler.

You could also do some research on [metalink](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: Speculation follows.**

The code it's complaining about, line 104, column 31 in file `_default_types.h`, is:

```
#elif  defined(LLONG_MAX) && (LLONG_MAX > 0x7fffffff)
                              ^ column 31
```

`LLONG_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>`.  On Cygwin, the definition is:

```
#define LLONG_MAX __LONG_LONG_MAX__
```

which refers to this:

```
#ifndef __LONG_LONG_MAX__
#define __LONG_LONG_MAX__ 9223372036854775807LL
#endif
```

The type `long long` and the `LL` suffix for `long long` integer constants are a new feature in C99.  In C prior to C99 (unless it's supported as an extension), `9223372036854775807LL` would be a syntax error.  I can imagine that a parser might interpret it as the syntactically valid constant `9223372036854775807L` followed by `L`.  (That wouldn't actually be a correct interpretation, but it's a syntax error anyway.)

I haven't used Ora*C, but my guess is that it has to parse its input code, which is a combination of C and SQL, producing pure C output.  (Is that correct?)  If the Ora*C parser doesn't understand the type `long long`, or a `...LL` literal, it could produce the kind of error you're seeing.

Something that really raises my suspicions is this line in your `pcscfg.cfg` file:

```
code=kr_c
```

That probably tells Ora*C to treat its input as K&R style (i.e., pre-standard) C code.  Consult your documentation and see if there's an option to tell it to process C99 code, or at least something more modern than K&R C.

[This web page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_10opt.htm) suggests that `code=ansi_c` is a recognized option.  Try that.

Or is the error coming from the C compiler that's invoked by Ora*C?  What C compiler are you using?  If it's not gcc, can you configure it to use gcc?

Comment: Are Ora*C and Pro*C the same thing?

Comment: Ora*c isn't a thing.   Pro*C is a preprocessor that comes with Oracle, which reads from the .pc file, and replaces the embedded sql with a set structures and function calls that do the actual work.  The output file is generally a .c file.   That .c file then gets compiled by the native compiler, and linked with a specific set of Oracle libraries.

Comment: The PCC in the error message identifies it as the Pro*C pass.